# how to split string into double char with double quotes in python?

Tags: python

if I give input  = development

output :

"de" , "ve" , "lo" , "pm" , "en" , "t"

how to create these programme

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Please read this to help you to ask a better question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -2):

s = '"Canada", "Japan", "Germany", "Russia"'
l = ['"{}"'.format(s) for s in s.split('"') if s not in ('', ', ')]

for item in l:
print(item)

Comment: i want output like this ( "ca" , "na" , "da") , split into two character not a word help me